# Spring cache using @Cacheable during @PostConstruct does not work

Tags: java, postconstruct, spring-cache

related to the commit in spring framework https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/5aefcc802ef05abc51bbfbeb4a78b3032ff9eee3

the initialisation is set to a later stage from *afterPropertiesSet()* to *afterSingletonsInstantiated()*

**In short**: 
This prevents the caching to work when using it in a @PostConstruct use case.

**Longer version**:
This prevents the use case where you would

1. create serviceB with @Cacheable on a methodB
2. create serviceA with @PostConstruct calling serviceB.methodB

   ```
   @Component 
   public class ServiceA{

   @Autowired
   private ServiceB serviceB;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
       List<String> list = serviceB.loadSomething();
   }
   ```

This results in org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport not being initialised now and thus not caching the result.

```
protected Object execute(CacheOperationInvoker invoker, Object target, Method method, Object[] args) {
   // check whether aspect is enabled
   // to cope with cases where the AJ is pulled in automatically
   if (this.initialized) {
//>>>>>>>>>>>> NOT Being called
      Class<?> targetClass = getTargetClass(target);
      Collection<CacheOperation> operations = getCacheOperationSource().getCacheOperations(method, targetClass);
      if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(operations)) {
         return execute(invoker, new CacheOperationContexts(operations, method, args, target, targetClass));
      }
   }
//>>>>>>>>>>>> Being called
   return invoker.invoke();
}
```

My workaround is to manually call the initialisation method:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfigClass{

  @Inject
  private CacheInterceptor cacheInterceptor;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    cacheInterceptor.afterSingletonsInstantiated();
  }
```

This of course fixes my issue but does it have side effects other that just being called 2 times (1 manual and 1 by the framework as intended)

My question is:
"Is this a safe workaround to do as the initial commiter seemed to have an issue with just using the afterPropertiesSet()"

Comment: The `@PostConstruct` gives no guarantees that proxies have already been created (that is the same reason why `@Transactional` doesn't work for `@PostConstruct` methods. The `@PostConstruct` method is called right after construction and after injection of the dependencies but almost always before the point that proxies have been created. Why do you need it in a `@PostConstruct` method? In general an `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` is beter of implementing the `SmartInitializingSingleton` interface instead of `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We use the postconstruct to initialize a bean with values taken from another service (which has @Cacheable on its methods) We expected that these values would be cached even when using a postconstruct. If this is not the case then a java doc would benefit the framework as other developers might not be aware of this as well. Will try the SmartInitializingSingleton instead. Thanks!

Comment: This is explained in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-lifecycle-default-init-destroy-methods) read the last paragraph of that section.

Answer (score 7):

As Marten said already, you are not supposed to use any of those services in the `PostConstruct` phase because you have no guarantee that the proxy interceptor has fully started at this point.

Your best shot at pre-loading your cache is to listen for `ContextRefreshedEvent` (more support coming in 4.2) and do the work there. That being said, I understand that it may not be clear that such usage is forbidden so I've created [SPR-12700](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12700) to improve the documentation. I am not sure what javadoc you were referring to.

To answer your question: no it's not a safe workaround. What you were using before worked by "side-effect" (i.e. it wasn't supposed to work, if your bean was initialized before the `CacheInterceptor` you would have the same problem with an older version of the framework). Don't call such low-level infrastructure in your own code.

Answer (score 5):

Just had the exact same problem as OP and listening to `ContextRefreshedEvent` was causing my initialization method to be called twice. Listening to `ApplicationReadyEvent` worked best for me.
Here is the code I used

```
@Component
public class MyInitializer implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        //doing things
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Autowire `ApplicationContext` and invoke method call using :

```
applicationContext.getBean(RBService.class).getRawBundle(bundleName, DEFAULT_REQUEST_LANG);
```

where `getRawBundle` is `Cacheable` method.

Answer (score 0):

> The @PostConstruct gives no guarantees that proxies have already been created

[image]

when use @Cacheable during @PostConstruct, `this.initialized` is false, and Will not execute operation cache related code.