# @Cacheable doesn't intercept the method, cache is always empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

I have a method as following:

```
@Cacheable(value = "SAMPLE")
public List<SomeObj> find() {
     // Method that initiates and returns the List<SomeObj> and takes around 2-3 seconds, does some logging too
}
```

And I am enabling caching in one of my configuration classes:

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public SomeConf extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    // Here I also initialize my classes with @Cacheable annotation

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCaches(Collections.singletonList((new ConcurrentMapCache("SAMPLE"))));
        return cacheManager;
    }


    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
        return new SimpleCacheResolver(cacheManager());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new SimpleKeyGenerator();
    }

}
```

I have the following in my `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.14.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I am declaring a `CacheManager` as follows:

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(){
    SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
    cacheManager.setCaches(Collections.singletonList((new ConcurrentMapCache("SAMPLE"))));
    return cacheManager;
}
```

When I get an `@Autowired` `CacheManager` instance into one of my `@Service`s I can see that there exists a cache with name `"SAMPLE"`, but its entries are always empty. I call again and again the method `find()`, but it doesn't seem to populate the cache.

I have tried to put an argument (say `int a`) to the `find()` method and put it as `key = "#a"` to `@Cacheable`, but nothing changed.

When I try to recreate the issue in an isolated environment, I can see that it works properly. But when I add my dependencies (non open-source company libraries, which include an `EhCache` configuration as well) it doesn't work. How can I debug this, what am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

I have also tried to use `cacheManager = myCacheManager` in `@Cacheable` as well. No luck.

**Update 2:**

I am using `AspectJ` and Spring AOP. I think that it may have something to do with it. I have tried `@EnableCaching(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)` with `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` but same thing.

**Update 3:**

I was finally able to reproduce the issue, here it is: [client-api-cache](https://github.com/hasancansaral/client-api-cache)

Basically when you run the application and `telnet localhost 9000` after you send any line to it, it should print `NOT CACHED` once even though the method is called twice in `CachedController` (Second coming from the cache). But it prints twice.

Comment: Is there an ehcache.xml file on the classpath which defines a cache named "find():List<SomeObj>"?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. There are two cases here: 1) I don't explicitly configure a `CacheManager` and Spring configures one `GuavaCacheManager`, so `ehcache.xml` is irrelevant. 2) When I explicitly define a `CacheManager` `@Bean` with `EhCacheManager` and put an ehcache.xml which defines a cache named "find():List<SomeObj>" (actually it doesn't accept the `<` chars so I had to replace the cache name but still). In both cases, couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @AndrewS Can you think of anything else with the updated question? Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm `SomeConf` is scanned?  `find()` doesn't have a parameter so not sure what it would use for a key - maybe get the Spring source to see if the cache proxy class is actually being invoked.

Comment: @AndrewS I can confirm that `@SomeConf` is scanned. I have also tried to put an argument (`int a`) to the `find()` method and put it as `key = "#a"` to `@Cacheable`, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause is that you are misusing "afterPropertiesSet". So, what you are doing is endless loop and never pass control back to the Spring pipeline, so Spring isn't able to init caching facility properly.

Check out code which fixes our problem: https://dumpz.org/cbx8h28KeAss

Comment: Yes, I've figured that out!

Answer (score 1):

As Andrews S noted, this does sound like colliding caches in the auto configuration.

[`@EnableCaching`'s javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/EnableCaching.html) has some useful notes regarding how the `cacheManager` is selected and, specifically, an idea on how to proceed. What you'd do in this case is establish a `CachingConfigurer` to select your cache - perhaps you can just extend `CachingConfigurerSupport` (as in example below) and be done.

> A bean of type `CacheManager` must be registered, as there is no reasonable default that the framework can use as a convention. And whereas the `<cache:annotation-driven>` element assumes a bean named "cacheManager", `@EnableCaching` searches for a cache manager bean by type. Therefore, naming of the cache manager bean method is not significant.
>
> For those that wish to establish a more direct relationship between `@EnableCaching` and the exact cache manager bean to be used, the `CachingConfigurer` callback interface may be implemented. Notice the `@Override`-annotated methods below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class AppConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

     @Bean
     public MyService myService() {
         // configure and return a class having @Cacheable methods
         return new MyService();
     }

     @Bean
     @Override
     public CacheManager cacheManager() {
         // configure and return an implementation of Spring's CacheManager SPI
         SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
         cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("default")));
         return cacheManager;
     }

     @Bean
     @Override
     public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
         // configure and return an implementation of Spring's KeyGenerator SPI
         return new MyKeyGenerator();
     }
}
```

> This approach may be desirable simply because it is more explicit, or it may be necessary in order to distinguish between two `CacheManager` beans present in the same container.
>
> Notice also the `keyGenerator` method in the example above. This allows for customizing the strategy for cache key generation, per Spring's `KeyGenerator` SPI. Normally, `@EnableCaching` will configure Spring's `SimpleKeyGenerator` for this purpose, but when implementing `CachingConfigurer`, a key generator must be provided explicitly. Return `null` or `new SimpleKeyGenerator()` from this method if no customization is necessary.
>
> `CachingConfigurer` offers additional customization options: it is recommended to extend from `CachingConfigurerSupport` that provides a default implementation for all methods which can be useful if you do not need to customize everything. See [`CachingConfigurer` Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CachingConfigurer.html) for further details.

You may also find this thread useful: [How to have multiple cache manager configuration in spring cache java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570211/how-to-have-multiple-cache-manager-configuration-in-spring-cache-java)

Edit:

So thankfully I have a project using caching and wrote this little bit:

```
@Bean
@Override
public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
    return new SimpleCacheResolver(cacheManager()) { 

        @Override
        protected Collection<String> getCacheNames(CacheOperationInvocationContext<?> context) {
            Collection<String> toReturn = super.getCacheNames(context);
            toReturn.forEach(System.out::println);
            return toReturn;
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends Cache> resolveCaches(CacheOperationInvocationContext<?> context) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(context.getArgs()));
            System.out.println(context.getClass());
            System.out.println(context.getMethod());
            System.out.println(context.getOperation());
            return super.resolveCaches(context);
        }
    };
}
```

Aside from seeing my established cache names pop out, I do note that context is outputting:

> []
>
> class org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext
>   public abstract ...transferobjects.CacheContainer ...service.LookupService.getCacheSelections()
>
> Builder[public ...transferobjects.CacheContainer ...dao.LookupFacade.getCacheSelections()] caches=[cacheselections] | key='' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='true'

The `context.getClass()` output is of interest, given your Aspect question. That said I have a very similar logging/timing aspect in my own code that isn't causing any confusion for the rest of the caching. Try my resolver out and see if the output is instructive on what calls are being made against the cache code.

Edit #2:

The TLDR issue appears to be that we're expecting `@Cacheable` to work in places where it can't - mainly due to the fact that the framework hasn't fully brought itself up yet. You are using `InitializingBean` and I tried replacing that functionality with `@PostConstruct` which both fail.

[Spring cache using @Cacheable during @PostConstruct does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350082/spring-cache-using-cacheable-during-postconstruct-does-not-work)

I got your github code. I initially ran into the blocking issue you reported in the other thread but, in the interest of pursuing one thing at a time, I just commented out that blocking code and called `service.cachedMethod()` directly.

I ran your jar file with --trace and noted that the cacheManager was scanned and created, but it wasn't initially obvious to me when it was being invoked. So, no big deal, I just had the bean method throw a `RuntimeException`. Upon doing that I noted that both your `NOT CACHED` lines print prior to that invocation - another hint that things aren't set up as expected.

Finally, I added `System.out.println(service.toString());` in your Controller's afterPropertiesSet() method and saw `com.company.client.api.domain.CachedServiceImpl@2bbfb8b` - your object, not a proxied object. Thus no caching.

So, in general, you'll need to rework how you're trying to enable this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is exactly what I do, without any difference. But I cannot make it work.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral So you've already modified your local `@Configuration` `SomeConf` to extend `CachingConfigurerSupport`? You can update your post with a current snapshot, but I suppose you can also try overriding [`cacheResolver()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CachingConfigurerSupport.html#cacheResolver--) to try to debug the `CacheOperationInvocationContext` contents.

Comment: I have updated the question. 5th full day, with various tries, but still not working...

Comment: I am using Spring AOP and AspectJ annotations, and had an issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52517497/around-aspect-in-the-same-package-only-works-with-dependson). Do you think it has anything to do with it?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral Interesting, but I'm not sure it's related. See my updated answer for a cacheResolver to try in debugging.

Comment: I’ll try it asap. But from my understanding, my methods are not intercepted with `@Cacheable`. I put logging level to trace ( as Spring logs caching in trace level) and no logs are printed when the method is called. I would expect a hit or a miss log.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral Then I expect you're correct - you'll see no output. Then do you feel that your `execution(* com.package.to.MyService.myMethod(..)` is interfering with the caching interceptor? Perhaps you could (temporarily) rewrite to `execution(* com.package.to.MyService.*(..)` to check the effect? Also look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047520/how-to-make-spring-cacheable-work-on-top-of-aspectj-aspect

Comment: Yes, no output. Simply `@Cacheable` doesn't intercept. Disabled all `@Aspect`s but nothing changed. Don't know how to debug this further.

Comment: I have replicated the issue and put it to GitHub. Please find it [here](https://github.com/hasancansaral/client-api-cache).

Comment: @HasanCanSaral See edit #2 for an update based on your git hub code. I don't have good news for you. xP

Comment: I have put the blocking code in `afterPropertiesSet` into a new thread and let the framework fully bring itself up. It’s now working. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are **setting** your cache into cachemanager as below.

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public SomeConf {   

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("find():List<SomeObj>")));
        return cacheManager;
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't help. Spring actually autoconfigures a `CacheManager` but even if I manually configure one as you showed, it is not populated.